# swapping adjacent nodes in a Linked list

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I have problems swapping adjacent nodes in a linkedlist.

for ex:  input : 1->2->3->4->5->null
         output: 2->1->4->3->5->null

```
bool swapAdjacent(node** head)
{

//1->2->3->4->null

//2->1->4->3->null
if(head==NULL)
return 0;
node* current  = *head;
*head = (*head)->next ;
node* prev = NULL;
cout<<"head val "<<(*head)->data <<endl;
node* temp;
while( current!=NULL&&current->next!=NULL)
{
   temp = current->next ;  //1s pointer points to 2
   current->next = temp->next ;    // 1s pointer point to 3
   temp ->next = current;   //2s pointer shud point to 1
   prev = current;
   current = current->next ;
   //cout<<"data " <<current->data <<endl;

   if(current!=NULL)
   prev->next = current->next ;



}

return 1;
}
```

My code is not working whenever there are odd no of nodes. How to fix this ?

Comment: @Daniel Trebiien its not home work

Comment: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=3537658

Comment: @Jonathan:  the function does NOT return 1 unconditionally.
It returns 1 if it did work, and 0 if there was no work to do. (see the early-out if head==NULL at the top).

Comment: Why not just swap data (I mean these kinds of problems are there to test your Linkedlist sklils). But swapping data would be the fastest and easiest. If not whatever you're trying to achieve is correct.

Comment: @abelenky: The second edition of the question included the two lines with the condition - so my comment/question applied when asked but doesn't apply any more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why so complicated?

```
int swapAdjacent(node** head) {
  if (!*head || !(*head)->next)
    return 0;
  node* const sw = (*head)->next;
  (*head)->next = sw->next;
  sw->next = *head;
  *head = sw;
  swapAdjacent(&(sw->next->next));
  return 1;
}
```

Edit: changed return value.

Comment: Why not only swap data? Its simpler and cleaner :)

Comment: @damned: Because the data might not be just `int`s but any complex structure where copy construction takes a lot of time, or isn't defined to begin with. And I don't see how swapping data would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is wrong with your code, but I would approach it by showing the state the of list at each pass through the loop:

```
void printList(node* head)
{
    int cntr = 1;

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("(Node: %d. Name: %s) --> ", cntr, head->name);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

For this, make sure each node has a `name`, set to "1", "2", etc.
Then printout the state of the list on each pass, perhaps even each step!
And you should see what's going wrong.

Comment: the last odd element is missing

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct s_sll
{
    int info;
    struct s_sll *link;
};
typedef s_sll node;
class sll
{
    public:
        static int cou;
        node *first;
        sll()
        {
        first=NULL;
        cou++;
        }
        node*create_node(int val);
        node*del_val();
        void disp();
        void swap_adjcent();
        ~sll()
        {
        delete first;
        cou--;
        }
};
void disp_all(sll **);
void despose(sll **);
int sll::cou=0;
void sll::swap_adjcent()
{
    node *temp,*a,*b;
    a=first;
    b=a->link;
    temp=b->link;
    a->link=temp->link;
    b->link=a;
    first=b;
    while(b!=NULL)
    {
        a=temp;
        b=temp->link;
        temp=b->link;
        if(temp->link!=NULL)
        {
        a->link=temp->link;
        b->link=a;
        a=temp->link;
        }
        else
        {
        a->link=temp;
        b->link=a;
        }
    }
    delete temp;
}
node* sll::create_node(int val)
{
    node *save,*temp;
    temp = new s_sll;
    temp->info=val;
    temp->link=NULL;
    if(first==NULL)
        first=temp;
    else
    {
        save=first;
        while(save->link!=NULL)
            save=save->link;
        save->link=temp;
    }
    return first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static node adjacent_reversal(node head)
{
   node temp = null;
   if(head == null)
       return null;
   if(head.next == null)
   {
       head.next = null;
       return head;
   }
   temp = adjacent_reversal(head.next.next);
   node temp1 = head.next;
   head.next.next = head;
   head.next = temp;
   return temp1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you take two pointers ...
Initially p1 points to 1st node and p2 to 2nd node

and iterate it in a loop untill the p2 points to null...
 and loop increment should be

```
 p1=(p1->next)->next;
 p2=(p2->next)->next;
 //swap the node pointed by these two pointers ..
```

this will work pretty well..